# MikTex console already running

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, uninstallation, miktex, texstudio

I am using VS Code with Miktex and I want to update my Miktex distribution or packages. However, I cannot open the Miktex Console since I get the following message:

[image]

I tried to search Miketx in my Task Manager to end it and open it again but it does not appear. How can I update it or open the console?

I tried uninstalling it via Control Panel but I get the same message, and I cannot even uninstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that MikTex was somehow bugged. To solve it just go to ProgramData/MikTex and delete the folder. Then I was able to install the packages again.